# Sometime when i Deserialize it wont load the ArrayList java

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I'm saving my ArrayList by Serializing it:

```
public void Save(){
    try{
    FileOutputStream ficheiro = new FileOutputStream("Gravacao");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(ficheiro);
    out.writeObject(ClassListas.ListaCliente);
    out.writeObject(ClassListas.ListaFornecedor);
    out.writeObject(ClassListas.ListaPessoa);
    out.writeObject(ClassListas.ListaStocks);
    out.writeObject(ClassListas.ListaVenda);
    out.writeObject(ClassListas.ListaRecurso);

    out.flush();
    out.close();

    ficheiro.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I deserialize it by:

```
public class FormPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public FormPrincipal() {
    initComponents();

    try{
    FileInputStream fx = new FileInputStream("Gravacao");
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fx);
    ClassListas.ListaCliente = (ArrayList<ClassCliente>) in.readObject();
    ClassListas.ListaFornecedor = (ArrayList<ClassFornecedor>) in.readObject();
    ClassListas.ListaPessoa = (ArrayList<ClassPessoa>) in.readObject();
    ClassListas.ListaRecurso = (ArrayList<ClassRecurso>) in.readObject();
    ClassListas.ListaStocks = (ArrayList<ClassStock>) in.readObject();
    ClassListas.ListaVenda = (ArrayList<ClassVenda>) in.readObject();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is how i have my ArrayLists declared:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import main.ClassPessoa;
import main.ClassCliente;
import main.ClassFornecedor;
import main.ClassStock;
import main.ClassVenda;
import main.ClassRecurso;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
*
* @author Skray
*/
public class ClassListas implements Serializable {
    //Listas
    public static ArrayList<ClassPessoa> ListaPessoa = new ArrayList<ClassPessoa>();
    public static ArrayList<ClassCliente> ListaCliente = new ArrayList<ClassCliente>();
    public static ArrayList<ClassFornecedor> ListaFornecedor = new ArrayList<ClassFornecedor>();
    public static ArrayList<ClassStock> ListaStocks = new ArrayList<ClassStock>();
    public static ArrayList<ClassVenda> ListaVenda = new ArrayList<ClassVenda>();
    public static ArrayList<ClassRecurso> ListaRecurso = new ArrayList<ClassRecurso>();
}
```

The problem is, sometimes, when I Deserialize this it won't load to ArrayList, but when I close and open again it Deserializes... Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Consider following Java naming conventions. Variables and methods should be camelCase. This doesn't solve your problem, but it's important for the future. We also need code we can paste right into out IDEs and compile - this makes troubleshooting easier.

Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can write your ClassListas instance instead of reading and writing each and every ArrayList seperately using following line

```
ClassListas.ListaCliente = (ArrayList<ClassCliente>) in.readObject();
ClassListas.ListaFornecedor = (ArrayList<ClassFornecedor>) in.readObject();
ClassListas.ListaPessoa = (ArrayList<ClassPessoa>) in.readObject();
ClassListas.ListaRecurso = (ArrayList<ClassRecurso>) in.readObject();
ClassListas.ListaStocks = (ArrayList<ClassStock>) in.readObject();
ClassListas.ListaVenda = (ArrayList<ClassVenda>) in.readObject();

out.writeObject(ClassListas.ListaCliente);
out.writeObject(ClassListas.ListaFornecedor);
out.writeObject(ClassListas.ListaPessoa);
out.writeObject(ClassListas.ListaStocks);
out.writeObject(ClassListas.ListaVenda);
out.writeObject(ClassListas.ListaRecurso);
```

Then the object is loaded from file during component initialisation only you can move code to separate method

```
public ClassListas readFromFile( String file) {
    ClassListas classListas = null ;
    try{
        FileInputStream fx = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fx);
        classListas = (ClassListas) in.readObject();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if( fx != null )
            fx.close();
    }
    return classListas;
}

public void writeToFile( String file,ClassListas classListas ) {
    try{
        FileOutputStream ficheiro = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(ficheiro);
        out.writeObject(classListas);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if( ficheiro != null )
            ficheiro.close();
    }
}
```

You can use call readFromFile and writeToFile in Load and save button of the form.